# Subset dataframe using counter that resets to 1 and create dataframe for each subset

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that I need to break into multiple, smaller dataframes.

There is an integer index, which starts at 1 and counts up. When it resets to 1, I need to start creating a new dataframe.

```
df <- cbind(c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4), c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"))

#end results should be: 
df1 <- df[1:5, ]
df2 <- df[6:9, ]
```

How do I do this programmatically? I can find where all of the "1"s are, but how to I go row-wise and break it into different dataframes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, `df` is a character matrix, not a `data.frame`. To define a `data.frame` object use e.g. `data.frame(index = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4), value = c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i")`

Find the index of the first value of each group, then split on groups. You do not need to perform any rowwise operation.

```
df <- data.frame(index = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4), value = c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"))
 
split(df, cumsum(df$index == 1))
```

result is a list of `data.frame` objects:

```
$`1`
  index value
1     1     a
2     2     b
3     3     c
4     4     d
5     5     e

$`2`
  index value
6     1     f
7     2     g
8     3     h
9     4     i
```

Comment: This is really elegant, and works as expected, thanks! 
I don't understand the cumsum part, though. The cumsum of the index column by itself is just a cumulative sum. How does cumsum == 1 tell split where to split it?

Comment: The expression you asked about, `cumsum == 1` is never used. It's checking `cumsum(df$index == 1)` which is very different. `df$index == 1` yields `c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE)`. Logical values are equivalent to integers 0 and 1, so `cumsum()`, the cumulative sum function, yields `c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)`. `split.data.frame` separates a data.frame into sets of all records at the same index positions as the positions that share a unique value in the second argument to `split.data.frame`, `f`.

Comment: That was very helpful, and that's a useful thing. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach with indexes and a loop. We create `i1` to store the rows where there is `1`. Then we compute the final position in `i2`. After that we create a list and use a loop to store the new data. Finally, we assign names and release to envir using `list2env`. Here the code:

```
#Create index
i1 <- which(df[,1]=='1')
i2 <- i1[-1]-1
#Test for dim
if(length(i2==1)){i2 <- c(i2,nrow(df))}
#Create a list
List <- list()
#Loop
for(j in 1:length(i1))
{
  List[[j]] <- df[i1[j]:i2[j],]
}
#Assign names
names(List) <- paste0('df',1:length(List))
#Set to envir
list2env(List,envir = .GlobalEnv)
```